# Making a conjecture concerning a certain upper-triangular matrix

Tags: matrix, experimental-mathematics

I have searched for commands which will let me to create matrices and do matrix operations, but I don't know how to apply *Mathematica* to the following exercise.

> Make a conjecture for the result of `A*A*A`, where `A` is an n x n matrix of the form

[image: A*A*A matrix of nxn rows]

I would like to know if *Mathematica* can calculate `A*A*A` and the approach I could use to carry out the calculation.

Comment: A.A.A gives the desired product. See the command `Dot`

Comment: Is this a school homework exercise? We accept such questions, but ask that they be tagged as such.

Answer (score 2):

Bill s already gave an answer as a comment. An explicit proof of the conjecture can be obtained by noting that
$$(A^3)_{il}=A_{ij}A_{jk}A_{kl}=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^N\text{Boole}[i\leq j]\text{Boole}[j\leq k]\text{Boole}[k\leq l]\\
=\sum_{j=1}^N\text{Boole}[i\leq j]\sum_{k=1}^N\text{Boole}[j\leq k]\text{Boole}[k\leq l]\\
=\sum_{j=1}^N\text{Boole}[i\leq j]\sum_{k=1}^N\text{Boole}[j\leq k\wedge k\leq l\ ]\\
=\sum_{j=1}^N\text{Boole}[i\leq j]\left(\text{Boole}[j\leq l](l-j+1)\right)\\
=\sum_{j=1}^N\text{Boole}[i\leq j\wedge j\leq l](l-j+1)\\
=\text{Boole}[i\leq l]\left[\left(\sum_{j=i}^l(l+1)\right)-\left(\sum_{j=i}^lj\right)\right]\\
=\text{Boole}[i\leq l]\left((l+1) (-i+l+1)+\frac{1}{2} (i-l-1) (i+l)\right)\\
=\frac{1}{2}\text{Boole}[i\leq l] (i-l-2) (i-l-1)$$
where Einstein notation was used in the first step.

In Mathematica, the conjecture can be obtained by noting the following:

```
a = Table[Boole[a <= b], {a, 15}, {b, 15}];
a.a.a // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
>  1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36 & 45 & 55 & 66 & 78 & 91 & 105 & 120 \\
>  0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36 & 45 & 55 & 66 & 78 & 91 & 105 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36 & 45 & 55 & 66 & 78 & 91 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36 & 45 & 55 & 66 & 78 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36 & 45 & 55 & 66 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36 & 45 & 55 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36 & 45 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 & 36 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & 28 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 6 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

which is the same as the formula I stated previously (for the case $N=15$).

Comment: You can let _Mathematica_ do the work with `Simplify[Sum[
  Sum[Boole[i <= p] Boole[p <= q] Boole[q <= j], {p, 1, n}], {q, 1, 
   n}], Assumptions -> {(i | j | n) \[Element] Integers, i <= j, 
   i <= n, j <= n}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Yeah, I just wanted to show him how to solve the recurrence by hand, rather than by using Mathematica, since it sounded like his question was from a math course.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is the most accurate and well developed solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

code examples for n x n triangularMatrix

```
Clear@"`*"
upperTriangularMatrix[n_][f_] := 
 SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i <= j -> f[i, j], {n, n}]
lowerTriangularMatrix[n_][f_] := 
 SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> f[i, j], {n, n}]

(* examples *)
upperTriangularMatrix[10][1 &] // MatrixForm
lowerTriangularMatrix[10][1 &] // MatrixForm
lowerTriangularMatrix[10][#1*#2 &] // MatrixForm

a = upperTriangularMatrix[10][1 &]
a . a . a // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrixExamples]